# How to implement the nanoScroller so that it works correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure I am missing something obvious and I have checked the other questions regarding this but none seem to have exactly my issue. I am new to Javascript but I'm sure this is a very simple script to implement on a website. If I can get it to work I can edit it from there and see how it works to further enhance it or remove from it.

Here is my code so that you can see exactly how i have it in the .html file

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
<title>Example</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nanoscroller.css">
<script rel="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nanoscroller.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
/* START NanoSlider */
.nano { background: #bba; width: 500px; height: 500px; }
.nano .content { padding: 10px; }
.nano .pane   { background: #888; }
.nano .slider { background: #111; }
/* END NanoSlider */
</style>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".nano").nanoScroller();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="about" class="nano">
    <div class="content">
         This is the content box and it should be scrolling but it is not!! =/.  
    </div> 
</div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fcJr3/1/

Maybe I am linking in or refering to required files wrong? or possibly NOT linking in or referring to all the files I am suppose to?

As you can see in the JSFiddle I only get the box. I don't get the scroll bar or any of the effects. Your help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: this is the nanoSlider here: http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery library itself. You can download it or run it straight from the google cdn i.e.
 `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

In your fiddle you need to include jquery using the dropdown top left i.e.
http://jsfiddle.net/fcJr3/2/

Comment: hy, you can update the jsfiddle link because dont work now,tks